# htaccess 404 include page

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I know I can redirect to a 404 page with htaccess, but can I just include the custom 404 page I have into the URL that is causing the 404? For example, someone types in blahwat.php, which is not on the server, can I keep them on that page but instead of the apache 404 can I have it include my custom 404 page?

Answer (score 1):

Using `ErrorDocument` does *not* redirect, so I don't know why you're bringing redirection up.

In any case, if there *was* a page at the URL then you wouldn't be getting a 404 in the first place.